# Selenium WebDriver - Finding Elements using cssSelector and nth child

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-ide

```
<ul>
<li class="active">
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>
    <span class="title">Home</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i><br>
    <span class="title">Posts</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><br>
    <span class="title">Events</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i><br>
    <span class="title">My Activity</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i><br>
    <span class="title">Assessments</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to locate the respective span element. I want to check the order of the span elements using css selector. So when I use selenium IDE,I will verify it like below(using nth child concept).

verifyText  |  css=.title:nth(0)  |  Home 
verifyText  |  css=.title:nth(1)  |  Posts 
verifyText  |  css=.title:nth(2)  |  Events 
verifyText  |  css=.title:nth(3)  |  My Activity 
verifyText  |  css=.title:nth(4)  |  Assessments

But when I do the same thing in Selenium WebDriver I am not able to locate the elements with the order which I did using Selenium IDE.

Below are the codes that I used in WebDriver and it dint work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".title:nth(0)")); // to locate the "Home" element

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".title:nth-of-type(0)")); // to locate the "Home" element

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".title:nth-child(0)")); // to locate the "Home" element
```

Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can generate the css-selector from `ul` like `ul > li:nth-child(1)` for home. See below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(1)")); >> home
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(2)")); >> posts
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(3)")); >> events
```

also reachin span is the same:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > span")); >> home
```

Comment: OP is asking for CSS selector.

Comment: @JeffC it is css selector

Comment: Sorry... I have no idea what I was thinking when I said that.

Comment: @JeffC You ara rigtht it was written XPath in explanation and corrected by drkthng check edited link.

Answer (score 7):

do you need css specifically? if not, you can also go for xpath, which imho *reads* better/clearer:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='title'])[0]")); // home
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='title'])[1]")); // posts
...
```

Comment: Css selector is faster than xpath.

Comment: Yes, Css selector is faster, but we're talking microseconds of difference (which is generally negligilbe when working with Selenium). 

Xpath also indexes from `1` and not from `0`, so the correct implementation would be

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='title'])[1]")); // home
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='title'])[2]")); // posts
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
        <div class=parent>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

If you already have the parent element and just need to find nth child

```
parent.find_element_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(2)')
```

would select the second div

Answer (score 0):

**We can write this way-**

To get all the span text like-

- Home
- Posts
- Events
- My Activity
- Assessments
  **Then** 
  `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul>li>a span:nth-child(3)"));`

  **and** 
  To get individual **span text** then you need to pass the index position in nth-child(index) method.
  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(1)>a span")).getText();//Home driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(2)>a span")).getText();//Posts driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(3)>a span")).getText();//Events driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(4)>a span")).getText();//My Activity driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(5)>a span")).getText();//Assessments` 
  For more details please visit- [CSS Selector in Details](http://avinashpandeblogsonseleniumautomation.blogspot.com/2019/10/css-selector-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul>li:nth-of-type(1)>a>')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.