# Driver find element with selenium

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, selenium

Im using java programming. Now, here web code;

```
<button class="btn-link" data-sugg-sources="full_name" data-sugg-technik="make_initial_and_name">NG1ulkan</button>
```

if i right click and copy > css selector, web is giving me this code;

'.suggestions > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)'

Now question is : How can i find this element with this selector and how can i focus and click with selenium java?
and also im using JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; in my code for focus

Comment: could you not find the element by its `class` ?

Comment: no, there are 5 different buttons, so i must select according to this selector '.suggestions > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`.suggestions > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)` is nothing but `cssSelector`; it just like xpath to locate elements present on a webpage, only that it is based upon css values

As you stated you are using `JavascriptExecutor` so you can use following code to click this element:

```
  js.executeScript("document.querySelector('.suggestions > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)').click();");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium's Java API you're going to use [`WebDriver.findElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and [`By.cssSelector`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#cssSelector-java.lang.String-):

```java
String selector = ".suggestions > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)";
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector));
```

See also [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939463/5000129).