# Selenium: How to find any ancestor based on one of ancestor's attribute using IWebElement.FindElement()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Let's say I have this HTML

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
 <div>
  <h6>My Header 1</h6>              
 <div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="class1">Text 2</span>       
    <span class="class2"></span>
   </label>
  <div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item-wrapper">
 <div>
  <h6>My Header 2</h6>              
 <div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="class1">Text 2</span>       
    <span class="class2"></span>
   </label>
  <div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How do I get to any child to the common parent, i.e. `<div class="item-wrapper">`? In this case, the attribute is the class. However, the attribute could be anything that can identify the common ancestor.

```
var xPathToAncestor = "ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']";
var ancestor = child.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathToAncestor)
```

I've tried so many combinations `//ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']`, `.//ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']`, but nothing is working.

Comment: Which _child_ are you looking at with respect to the ancestor `<div class="item-wrapper">`?

Comment: One problem is that you need to be specific as to which two (or more elements) you want to find a common ancestor of. If you choose the INPUT or the SPANs, the common ancestor is the LABEL, and so on. You can't find a "common" ancestor with just one element.

Comment: @JeffC, that's a good point. That's why I said "any parent" because I want it to be a placeholder. All I need is a working code so that I can replace the above xpath with to string variables. The above code is just to illustrate what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Richard77 the question content says "How do I get to any child to the common parent, i.e. <div class="item-wrapper">? "    and answers are for that . Update ypur question

Comment: //span/ancestor::div[@class="item-wrapper"] but also added answer to find a parent , this locator finds div element which is a parent of span tag

Comment: I think there's a lot of confusion with your question. In it you ask, "How do I get **TO** any child to the common parent?" I think you typo'd there and meant to state, "How do I get **FROM** any child to the common parent? Is that correct? If so, would you please update your question? Some more examples might help clarify also.

Comment: @Richard77 if this what you wanted to then just use `var xPathToAncestor = "./ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']";` see the '.' infront it says the child is the context node . That will fix your issue. I have added that to my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
//div[@class='item-wrapper']//span
```

this find span tags which are a direct and indirect child

To find direct child

```
//div[@class='item-wrapper']/span
```

**How to use ancestor:**

```
//ancestor::div[@class="item-wrapper"]
```

This finds an element with tag div and class item-wrapper , and is a parent of any child

```
//span/ancestor::div[@class="item-wrapper"]
```

In your case just change

```
var xPathToAncestor = "./ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']";
```

**See the '.' it indicates the child is the context node of xpath**

This finds an element with tag div and class item-wrapper , and is a parent element of span tag

```
//ancestor::div[@class="item-wrapper"]/span
```

finds span tag that is a direct child of class="item-wrapper" and div tag

```
//ancestor::div[@class="item-wrapper"]//span
```

finds span tag that is a direct or non direct child of class="item-wrapper" and div tag

Comment: @Richard77 did the answer solved your issue ? Adding .//ancestors should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To get to any child with respect to the common parent `<div class="item-wrapper">` you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Getting `<input type="checkbox" />` using *xpath*:

  ```
  //div[@class='item-wrapper']//h6[text()='My Header']//following::label[1]/input[1]
  ```
- Getting `<span class="class1">Text 1</span>` using *xpath*:

  ```
  //div[@class='item-wrapper']//h6[text()='My Header']//following::label[1]//span[@class='class1']
  ```

---

### Update

As per your question update, to get the common parent `<div class="item-wrapper">` you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ancestor` of *xpath* and text `Text 2`:

  ```
  //span[text()='Text 2']//ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']
  ```
- Using `ancestor` of *xpath* and `class="class1"` attribute:

  ```
  //span[@class='class1']//ancestor::div[@class='item-wrapper']
  ```

Comment: @Richard77 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using CSS selectors instead of XPath.

Using the HTML from your question as an example:

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
 <div>
  <h6>My Header</h6>              
 <div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="class1">Text 1</span>       
    <span class="class2"></span>
   </label>
  <div>
 </div>
</div>
```

To target `class="class1"` you would use this:

`var classOne = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".item-wrapper > div(2) > div > label > '.class1'"));`

1. This locates the `item-wrapper` class,
2. then the 2nd `div` (as the 1st `div` contains the `header`),
3. then the next `div`
4. then the `label`
5. then whatever has the class `class1`
6. Alternatively you could use the `span` instead of the class name. Which will make it `var classOne = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".item-wrapper > div(2) > div > label > span(1)));`. Because you want the first `span` rather than the 2nd.

Note that the CSS Selector for `class` is `.`. There are different CCS Selectors that you can use.

This [answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939198/selenium-webdriver-finding-elements-using-cssselector-and-nth-child) using CSS Selectors too.